# How to compile Elmer fem on macOS with OpenMPI, Hypre and Mumps

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, openmpi

I'm trying to modify the instructions in [this page](http://www.elmerfem.org/elmerwiki/index.php?title=Compiling_Elmer_parallel_version_(Linux)) to compile [Elmer](https://www.csc.fi/web/elmer) on macOS  (High Sierra 10.13.5).

I installed `gcc`, `cmake`, `open-mpi` and `hypre` from HomeBrew core and followed [this instruction](http://mumps.enseeiht.fr/index.php?page=links) to install `mumps` from `dpo/openblas`. I downloaded the source code with:

`svn checkout http://svn.code.sf.net/p/elmerfem/code/trunk elmerfem`

I made [this bash script](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/255ef7ea286e65d0d669b3b129857a30) following [the instructions in that page](http://www.elmerfem.org/elmerwiki/index.php?title=Compiling_Elmer_parallel_version_(Linux)) and make it executable `chmod u+x compile` and ran it `./compile`. However I get lots of warnings/errors which I don't know how to solve. I tried to direct the stream into a logfile which you can see in [the same GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/255ef7ea286e65d0d669b3b129857a30), but apparently it did not include everything. The last couple of lines I see in the stream are:

> Types.f90:354: Error: Can't open included file 'dmumps_struc.h'
>
> make[3](http://mumps.enseeiht.fr/index.php?page=links): *** [Types.o] Error 1
>
> make[2](https://www.csc.fi/web/elmer): *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>
> make[1](http://www.elmerfem.org/elmerwiki/index.php?title=Compiling_Elmer_parallel_version_(Linux)): *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2

I assumed it should be because the compiler somewhere is including the `dmumps_struc.h`header. so I tried editing the script adding the mumps static libraries in

`/usr/local/opt/mumps/libexec/lib`

and it didn't even compile the first modules either. I would appreciate it if you could help me know where is my mistake and how I can solve it.

**P.S.** I have updated the MUMPS installation with HomeBrew [here](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/no-available-formula-with-the-name-mumps/1580/3?u=foadsf).

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a question about the MUltifrontal Massively Parallel sparse direct Solver (MUMPS), but you've tagged it with the Massachusetts General Hospital Utility Multi-Programming System (MUMPS) tag.  That's an easy mistake to make.

You might have better luck getting your question answered if you change how it's tagged.

Ideally, some friendly Stack Overflow user with a sufficiently high reputation would create a new tag for the MUMPS Problem Solver, and differentiate it from the MUMPS nosql database.